# Trying to find an electronic single-pole multiple-throw switch

Tags: switches

I am trying to find an electronic component that does the following.

The electronic component is basically a switch, that can switch to many different wires, based on a given input. This input can be a digital binary number or an analog input. This is used for a very low current application.  I am an electronics beginner and I am not sure if such a component exists.

[image]

Comment: It's called a "CMOS analog switch (with digital control input)". But please clarify "very low current", is it for signal or is it for power? A 10 mA digital signal and a small 100 mA power supply are not the same.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you give more explanation about your project. You said, _"this input can be a digital binary number, or an analog input"_. Well, if the input is a "digital binary number", will it be 0 or 1? There are two kinds of inputs in this device: a **_data_** or **_signal_ input** (digital or analog?), and the **_control_ input**, which will let the device know which output will receive the "data" or "signal". Will the **_control_ input** be analog or digital? If you please could reword your question to explain what you have in mind, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: what is `many different wires`?

Comment: It's called an analog multiplexer.

Comment: 74HC4051 for example.

Comment: To get a meaningful answer, you'll need to give details of the circuits being switched.  These matter with many types of semiconductor switches in a way that they do not with mechanical ones.

Comment: CD4051  1 to 8 bidirectional analog. also 4052 & 4053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variations of the same thing.  Some are directional, and are called multiplexers (multiple inputs to one output) or demultiplexers (one input to many outputs).  This is particularly true for older parts specifically for digital signals.  Newer parts, and many parts for analog signals, are bi-directional - but again it depends on the type of signal.  Many analog switches designed specifically for audio are bi-directional, but most video switches are unidirectional.  I can't be more specific without more information about the signals you are switching.

Comment: this answered my question. what I need is a demultiplexer. thanks

Comment: Glad it helps.  What is the signal type you are dealing with?  Also, upvote?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to design a relatively uncomplicated circuit to achieve your goals.

It'll consist of 2 parts. The 'electronic switches' themselves and the interface to the rest of your design whether analog or digital.

I'd consider using either jfet's for the switches or analog transmission gates such as the widely used CD4016, 4051 or 4066 from the inexpensive CD4000 series or maybe something that can deal with a higher voltage range such as Siliconix's DG211, 308 etc..

The use of discrete jfet's is only really warranted when you need to preserve signal integrity to a large degree. For most applications an IC switch works well.

It's then a simple matter to 'decode' your switch selection input to a suitable format to drive the switches.

Comment: CD4052 and CD4053 also exist.